# Ada `Gprbuild` Shorter File Names, Organized into Directories

Tags: ada, gnat

Over the past few weeks I have been getting into Ada, for various different reasons. But there is no doubt that information regarding my personal reasons as to why I'm using Ada is out of scope for this question.

As of the other day I started using the `gprbuild` command that comes with the Windows version of [GNAT](https://www.adacore.com/community), in order to get the benefits of a system for managing my applications in a project-related manner. That is, being able to define certain attributes on a per-project basis, rather than manually setting up the compile-phase myself.

Currently when naming my files, their names are based off of what seems to be a standard for the `grpbuild`, although I could very much be wrong. For periods (in the package structure), a `-` is put in the name of the file, for underscores, an `_` is put accordingly. As such, a package by the name `App.Test.File_Utils` would have a file name of `app-test-file_utils`: `.ads` and `.adb` accordingly.

In the `.gpr` project file I have specified:

```
for Source_Dirs use ("app/src/**");
```

so that I am allowed to use multiple directories for storing my files, rather than needing to have them all in the same directory.

### The Problem

The problem that arises, however, is that file names tend to get very long. As I am already putting the files in a directory based on the package name contained by the file, I was wondering if there is a way to somehow make the compiler understand that the package name can be retrieved from the file's directory name.

That is, rather than having to name the `App.Test.File_Utils`' file name `app-test-file_utils`, I would like it to reside under the `app/test` directory by the name `file_utils`.

Is this doable, or will I be stuck with the horrors of eventually having to name my files along the lines of: `app-test-some-then-one-has-more_files-another_package-knew-test-more-important_package.ads`? Granted, I have not missed something about how an Ada application should actually be structured.

### What I have tried

I tried looking for answers in the [`package Naming` configuration of the `gpr` files in the documentation](http://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/companion_tools.html#package-naming), but to no avail. Furthermore I have been browsing the web for information, but decided it might be better to get help through Stackoverflow, so that other people who might struggle with this problem in the future (granted it is a problem in the first place) might also get help.

Any pointers in the right direction would be very helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [top-secret GNAT documentation](http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnat_ugn/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/the_gnat_compilation_model.html#file-naming-topics-and-utilities) there is a description of how to use non-default file names. It's a great deal of effort. You will probably give up, use the default names, and put them all in a single directory.

Comment: OP has already tried the documentation. That said, I agree completely with the use-default-filenames, use-single-directory recommendation.

Comment: OP had tried the gprbuild documentation, but not the GNAT documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simplify much of the effort by using GPS and letting it build your project file as you add files to your source directories.